# How do you join three tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I'm having a hard time joining three separate tables in `Oracle`. I'm never joined three tables before so I'm not well versed. My theory is below:

```
SELECT customer_num WHEN customer_num IS 104 -198, order_num
  FROM orders INNER JOIN items
    ON order_num, stock_num
    INNER JOIN stock
      ON stock_num, description
```

Essentially, I'm trying to start with the `ORDERS` table and pull the customer number (`customer_num`) specifically customer number `104 -108` and the `order_num` from the orders table. Then attach the orders table to the Items table and attach the `order_num` and `stock_num`, and lastly attach the stock table and pull out the `stock_num` and description.

Comment: Please read [help] and [ask] pages.  You don't show us the table schemas, sample input, or expected output, but we are supposed to divine a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this (based on the limited information about the schema)...

```
SELECT 
    O.CUSTOMER_NUM, 
    O.ORDER_NUM, 
    S.STOCK_NUM,
    S.DESCRIPTION
FROM 
    ORDERS O,
    ITEMS I,
    STOCK S
WHERE
    I.CUSTOMER_NUM >= 104
    AND I.CUSTOMER_NUM <= 198
    AND O.ORDER_NUM = I.ORDER_NUM
    AND I.STOCK_NUM = S.STOCK_NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is all over the place, and wouldn't work for a two-table join, or even querying a single table. Not sure where you got `WHEN` from, or the order of your clauses. Please review the [SQL reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm) to see how to join and how to filter. Anyway...

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT o.customer_num, o.order_num, i.stock_num, s.description
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN items i ON i.order_num = o.order_num
INNER JOIN stock s ON s.stock_num = i.stock_num
WHERE o.customer_num BETWEEN 104 AND 198;
```

The `WHERE` clause is being applied to the `orders` table to restrict which customers'  orders you get. I've assumed from your description that the `orders` and `items` tables have a common `order_num` column you can join on; and that the `items` and `stock` tables have a common `stock_num` column you can join on.

As OldProgrammer said, it would be helpful to include your table schemas in the question so assumptions don't need to be made, and showing sample data and expected output for that data would clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a JOIN is:

```
TableExpression [ INNER ] JOIN TableExpression
{
  ON booleanExpression |    USING clause
}
```

The booleanExpression is what the tables will be linked by.  So, in your example, something like this:

```
SELECT customer_num WHEN customer_num IS 104 -198, order_num
FROM orders INNER JOIN items
  ON orders.<some_column> = items.<some_column>
INNER JOIN stock
  ON items.<some_column> = stock.<some_column>
```